# Resetting the template engine, because it is initialized but empty - 503 error

Tags: ucommerce

I have an PaaS Application hosted on Azure. It's running Sitecore.NET 9.0.2 (rev. 180604) with Ucommerce 7.13.0.18309. Now everything had been running fine, until yesterday. One of Sitecore's config's was updated with a new Password, and the App was restarted. But since then, the Application is not responding at all, just getting 503 error. I can see the Ucommerce logs:

> 25020 11:00:09 INFO  Resetting the template engine, because it is initialized but empty. 25020 11:00:30 INFO  BuildTemplates() called.
>   25020 11:00:33 INFO  TemplateDataProvider.BuildTemplates(). 3122 ms

But prior to the App restart yesterday, we could see:

> 40340 10:17:20 INFO  Resetting the template engine, because it is initialized but empty.
>   40340 10:18:08 INFO  BuildTemplates() called.
>   40340 10:18:22 INFO  TemplateDataProvider.BuildTemplates(). 13928 ms
>   40340 10:18:35 INFO  Adding categories to cache took 2341 ms. 
>   40340 10:18:35 INFO  ContentNodeDataProvider.Initialize(). 2374 ms
>  
>   40340 10:18:35 INFO  Dependencies have been setup.
>   40340 10:19:17 INFO  Initializing the System Data Provider data 
>   40340 10:19:37 INFO  SystemDataProvider.InitializeData(). 20135 ms 
>   27400 10:19:37 INFO  Initializing the Product Data Provider data 
>   27400 10:19:37 INFO  Calculated the partition depth to be 1, based upon 179 products. 
>   27400 10:19:37 INFO  ProductsDataProvider.InitializeData(). 113 ms 
>   40340 10:19:38 INFO  Adding language to list of versions: en

It seems that something is unable to complete or some sort of lock. And in the Sitecore logs it just sits on - Sitecore is running in Standalone role:

> 20632 11:05:24 INFO  Cache created: 'ExperienceAnalytics.Sites' (max
>   size: 1MB, running total: 1302MB)

If I remove all Sitecore.uCommerce_ configs from /App_Config/Include (11 files) then restart the App, then Sitecore will start responding and everything is working as expected. So I just wanted to see if anyone had seen anything like this before, or how I can recover the App?

Addition:

We've already implemented this hotfix https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/910936 
**Deadlock causes site unresponsiveness on application start**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with Sitecore support, it was identified as being due to the deadlock on the application start. The deadlock is caused by the analytics aggregation thread and Sitecore thread which runs initialization pipeline. 
The scenario is as follows:

1. The first thread runs aggregation for the first time (once the first interaction hits analytics database) and tries to resolve types from configurations in the following method: 
   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.FlexibleMetrics.Framework.Plumbing.FlexibleDimensionConfigReader.ReadFromConfig()

When resolving a type from config a lock is acquired on the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider._resolvedServices dictionary.
During this type resolution a constructor of the Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Outcomes.Data.ItemDb.ItemOutcomeDefinitionRepository is called which tries to access the field of the analytics root item.
To do that a lock is requested on Sitecore.DependencyInjection.LazyResetable.InstanceLock object.

2. At the same time another thread executes custom **Synthesis.Pipelines.Initialize.CheckModelSynchronization.DoLogSync()** processor of the  pipeline.
   This processor then calls UCommerce.Sitecore.Security.SitecoreUserService.GetCurrentUserName() method which first accesses the field value and acquires lock on Sitecore.DependencyInjection.LazyResetable.InstanceLock and right after that tries to resolve dependency via a service provider.
   To do that a thread should lock on Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider._resolvedServices dictionary which is already held by the aggregation thread.  As the result application freezes.

Sitecore support provided a Hotfix specific to this Solution, but confirmed that this behavior is not expected and it was registered as a bug in their bug tracking system.

It's logged under the reference number 209972 - which looks like it relates to https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/910936